# Where can I find some smithing potions in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I'm wanting to know where I can find some smithing potions around Skyrim. I'm level 42 and I have tried looking at the alchemist shops and regular traders, but I just can't seem to find any. Some places I have found them are in caves and things like that but otherwise I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shop inventories are generated based on your level and refreshed every few days, so you could stand outside a shop and wait until you find such a potion (according to [this page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Potions), blacksmithing potions are on your list by level 10 and the best one by 30).  You can also use [this page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ingredients) to see which ingredients include "fortify smithing" and procure those ingredients to make the potions, which is probably the best solution anyway since alchemy is an extremely useful skill.

Loot is also based on level, so putting your smithing project on hold for a little while and dungeoneering should eventually net you a smithing potion.

Comment: My smithing is at 100 and I'm level 87 I would just like to make my weapons stronger but thanks, this really helps.